# Byobu unable to attach to running tmux

Tags: tmux, byobu

I´m a happy user of byobu, but recently I noted that I cannot attach anymore to open sessions.

With `ps aux | grep tmux` I can clearly see many tmux processes, but unfortunatly, when I try to attach with:

- `tmux attach`
- `byobu attach`

I get no results but a `no session` error. Moreover, with `byobu-select-session` I got a failed to connect to server instead.

There is a commant to connect tmux to a given socket, which I found using 
`lsof -U | grep '^tmux'`. But still no session attached. My session files are in /tmp/user/tmux-1000/default, but I can see some sockets being used.

From `ps aux` I can see that byobu launches tmux with: `tmux -2 -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session -n - /usr/bin/byobu-shell`

Unfortunately, either with `byobu -S path` or `byobu -L socketname` I am not able to attach to previously open session, and byobu simply start a new session.

Comment: Seems a very similar problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/6ugcnv/sometimes_not_possible_to_attach_to_running_tmux/

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar situation caused by accidentally removing the tmux socket in /tmp. The method [described here](https://rubenvarela.com/guides/recovering-tmux-when-its-socket-was-deleted/) solved the problem for me (either `killall -SIGUSR1 tmux` or `kill -USR1 $PID_FOR_RUNNING_TMUX`).